# How to improve performance with UNIQUE column SQLite Android

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with a UNIQUE column. it's for not add the same code "KEY_CODIALERTA + " TEXT UNIQUE". it works well but when I try to add the same code then I see error in "LogCat" saying that I cant add that code because is repeated. I would like to know if is normal or is there a way to avoid that errors

Thank you.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you're trying to add a raw to your db and it throws an error that the values are not unique. I guess that's what you wanted to see when you defined your db schema.

Comment: I know it's not a real error and is what I wanted but I just ask if is okey when the logcat show that error?. @SaeidFarivar

Comment: right, you probably are using something like e.printStackTract() in a catch block that's why you see the error. Anyways it's totally ok and I guess good to see errors in logcat.

Comment: if you are not catching the error you should do it:

import android.database.SQLException;
try {
    ... // your code here
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}